# Code reuse via inheritance and cross-delegation

Tags: c++, code-reuse

Assume I have the following class-hierarchy in C++:

```
class AbstractBaseClass
{
public:
    // Note:  Class is completely abstract! No data!
    AbstractBaseClass() {}
    virtual ~AbstractBaseClass() {}
    virtual std::string definedInVirtual() = 0;
    virtual std::string definedInDerived() = 0;
};

class Virtual : public virtual AbstractBaseClass
{
public:
    Virtual() {}
    virtual ~Virtual() {}

    std::string definedInVirtual()
    {
        return "definedInVirtual";
    }
};

class DerivedA : public Virtual
{
public:
    DerivedA() {}
    virtual ~DerivedA() {}

    std::string definedInDerived()
    {
        return "definedInDerivedA";
    }
};

class DerivedB : public Virtual
{
public:
    DerivedB() {}
    virtual ~DerivedB() {}

    std::string definedInDerived()
    {
        return "definedInDerivedB";
    }
};
```

In this case, calling `definedInVirtual()` on either `DerivedA` or `DerivedB`, the definition of `definedInVirtual()` on `Virtual` is called, via cross-delegation.  This is, then, a form of code reuse.

**What are the drawbacks to this method?  Is there a better way to achieve code reuse in this situation?**

**EDIT:**

The main reason I ask is there was a very large class that someone had developed with the plan of code reuse via inheritance (he since regrets doing this, but the class is large) that was super-classed by a new ABC due to adding a decorator derived from the new ABC to the object hierarchy. I need to add methods to the new ABC that need to be handled by the DerivedA and DerivedB, and for the decorator to handle via calling the internal instance of the ABC. My idea is to use the above technique...

Comment: You are not using cross-delegation here (not in the sense of sister class delegation mentioned in the [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.10) you cited in the comment). `definedInVirtual()` is called simply because it is inherited. Virtual inheritance or sister-class delegation doesn't have anything to do with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code re-use should be implemented through composition, not inheritance. Virtual inheritance is slow and extremely messy and should be avoided in nearly all designs.

Comment: slow, as in, an extra vtable pointer to follow on function calls?

Comment: @Sheepsimulator: It also invokes dynamic overheads even when casting to base types from derived types, and you can't static_cast back up. It also creates severe messes with member function pointers, and dynamic_cast can be substantially slower with virtual inheritance. This is all on top of slower function calls. Finally, maintaining constructor/destructor order with virtual inheritance can be quite nasty.

Comment: BTW - I agree with you on not using inheritance for reuse.  It's just that this class was written that way due to a misunderstanding of inheritance by the author of the class.  So I'm thinking - to do it right - I should take Virtual, pull it out of the hierarchy, and re-write DerivedA and DerivedB to have a member of type Virtual that handles the calls from the ABC?

Comment: @sheepsimulator: I'm not entirely sure that I understand. Post a small code sample of the *existing* code that needs fixing.

Comment: +1. Consider also that multiple inheritance will have slower dispatching to all but the first base (the dispatch through the vtable has to go to a thunk that rewrites the `this` pointer to adapt it to the final overrider type)... Inheritance is about code reuse, but in the opposite direction: You inherit so that all existing code that can already handle your base will work with your new behavior. Not so you can use the code in the base class... that can be achieved by other means.

Answer (score 1):

At the time when I'm writing this answer your question has some undefined and quite uncommon terms, "cross-delegation" and "superclassed" (which makes no sense in C++), and your classes don't make sense: what is the virtual inheritance for?

So, I'm sorry, but about the only thing that can be said as of now is to avoid the ungood things in the presented code:

- don't let pure value-producing methods be non-`const`, do add `const`.
- what DeadMG noted in his answer, that it's generally a good idea to avoid virtual inheritance.

In your case, at least with what you've shown at this point, the virtual inheritance isn't used for anything at all (your comment about "cross-delegation" might be it, but it doesn't make sense), so it's easy: remove that `virtual` keyword: it doesn't do anything useful here.

You might try to amend your question with a more relevant example, and without the buzzwords.

(This should ideally have been a comment, but too long for an SO comment. Oops, negativity. Not entirely happy-happy or pseudo-technical positive! Now the anonymous drive-by downvoters will probably be driving by, inspired by "The Weatherman". Oh well.)

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Cross-delegation is the term Cline used in the C++ FAQ for this:  http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.10

Comment: The second part of my question had to do with mutations over time, and yeah, it isn't straight-forward - I'll have to draw some diagrams that show the changes.

Comment: @sheepsimulator: re "cross-delegation", you'll notice that Marshall put that in quotes. Also, note that the code in the FAQ very different from your example. In short, "cross-delegation" is not a standard or well-known term. The term *dominance* is more well known, perhaps because the Visual C++ compiler has a habit of complaining about "inherited via dominance". But I don't think any arbitrarily chosen C++ person would likely know what "dominance" is, either, so concrete example very important (IMO). Cheers